# Send message to multiple facebook users

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, reference

Is there a way to achieve this?

This code is use to send message but pop ups a box where you can type your message
then send.

```
   FB.ui({
                      method: 'send',
                      to: '100007250800729',
                      link:'http://www.mysite.com',
                      redirect_url:location.href,
                      message: 'A request especially for one person.',
                      data: 'tracking information for the user'

                    });
```

is there a way I can send it immediately by executing the script without the pop up like this so i can send the message to multiple users

```
foreach(users as user) {
    method: 'send',
    to: user->id,
    link:'http://www.mysite.com',
    redirect_url:location.href,
    message: 'HEllo '.user->name.' A request especially for you.',
    data: 'tracking information for the user' 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send a message without a popup. One more thing, you can't write a predefined message.
Example :-

FB.ui({
                      method: 'send',
                      to: 100007250800729
                      link:'http://www.mysite.com',
                      redirect_url:location.href
                    });